# How to create a series of images with Javascript to form loading screen under another image?

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend, vs-web-site-project

I'm having a tough time trying to generate 10 little squares (every 1 second) in a row that would simulate pixels in a loading bar, while having them appear just under another image of a rabbit. Right now it's working but they appear forming a vertical line instead of a row.

This is the javascript code:

```
var rabbit = document.getElementById("rabbit");

  for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
   setTimeout(() => {
   var pixel = document.createElement('img');
   pixel.setAttribute('src', 'static/images/test/pixel.png');
   pixel.setAttribute('height', '10px');
   pixel.style.marginLeft = "10px";
   document.body.appendChild(pixel);
  rabbit.after(pixel);
}, i*1000+1500);
}
```

And this is the HTML tag of the rabbit image:

```
   <img id='rabbit' src='{% static 'images/cartelera_home/ghost.gif' %}' alt='' style='height:0px'>
```

I don't think it is relevant, but I'm using Django to build this website and bootstrap, and so far there's no CSS code in this page.

Just **any kind of help** will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm having a tough time trying to generate 10 little squares (every 1 second) in a row that would simulate pixels in a loading bar, while having them appear just under another image of a rabbit. Right now it's working but they appear forming a vertical line instead of a row.

This seems to be working as you expect unless I am mis-understanding. it looks like a progress bar - I just substituted your code with a blue box using a data uri.

You can see it here
[https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-wilbur-d2tuf?file=/index.html'](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-wilbur-d2tuf?file=/index.html%27)

Is it possible you have other code/styles interfering with the outcome?

Comment: Indeed it works like that when it is not attached to the object and yes that's how I want it. But then, as soon as I include the "rabbit.after(pixel);" line, the squares form a column instead of a row just under the rabbit image. I think it works in the code you sent because there is no rabbit image there, maybe!

Comment: Bought you a rabbit, https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-wilbur-d2tuf?file=/index.html

Comment: Haha, well then I was wrong, then it probably has something to do with bootstrap and my base.html from where the file is inheriting the code. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Glad to help, Please share what you thought was interfering.